# Nesting modules with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have one module called UserProvider that looks like this

```
var UserProvider = function(db) { ... }
UserProvider.prototype.createUser = function(email, password, callback) { ... }
UserProvider.prototype.findUserByEmail = function(email, callback) { ... }
...
exports.UserProvider = UserProvider;
```

And another module called ModelProvider that looks like this

```
var UserProvider = require('./user').UserProvider;
var ModelProvider = function() {
    ...
    this.User = new UserProvider(db);
}
exports.ModelProvider = ModelProvider;
```

But the line `this.User = new UserProvider(db);` doesn't allow me to access the `UserProvider` object in my main module that has included the `ModelProvider` module.

When I try to call this:

```
var ModelProvider = require('./model/model').ModelProvider;
var Model = new ModelProvider();

Model.User.findUserByEmail(email, function() {...});
```

It gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Object function Model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof Model))
        return new Model(doc, fields, skipId);
    model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
} has no method 'findUserByEmail'
```

I'm assuming there is some JavaScript trickery that I am missing to expose this down?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you would need to require the user module in the main module as well or also add the `UserProvider` to the `exports` object in the model module.

Comment: Right, but instantiating an instance of the user model depends on the database connection object, So I want the Model module to initialize it on its startup, and then expose it.

Comment: So presumably you have something like `var model = new ModelProvider()` in your main module, if you access `model.User` what do you get?

Comment: Original question edited with the error message

Comment: Looks like you have some sort of name clash going on there, the error seems to suggest you have a class named `Model` which it may be confusing with the instance you have created of `ModelProvider`

Comment: I just edited the question to show how the `Model` variable is created.  There is definitely not another class being defined with the name `Model`.

Comment: Is the constructor for `UserProvider` returning anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears to be happening in this case and the cause of your error is that `Model.User` is actually not an instance of `UserProvider` but appears to point to a function called `Model` defined as...

```
function Model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if(!(this instanceof Model))
        return new Model(doc, fields, skipId);
    model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
}
```

Now this assignment could be happen at three places within your code...

```
var Model = new ModelProvider();
// Here sets Model.User
Model.User.findUserByEmail(...);
```

Or...

```
function ModelProvider() {
    ...
    this.User = new UserProvider(db);
    // Here sets this.User
}
```

Or...

```
function UserProvider(db) {
    // Here as a return statement
}
```

I would guess the latter is probably where the issue is happening.

---

To be clear all of the following are possible in NodeJS...

**Importing a constructor from a module that didn't necessarily contain it...** To be clear you *shouldn't* do this but it is possible to chain the exports so that a module exposes items from other modules it imports. You *should* import modules explicitly.

module.js...

```
var Something = require("./something").Something;
exports.Something;
```

main.js...

```
var Something = require("./module").Something;
```

**Repeat** do *not* do this. Instead include what you need from the module that *owns* it and don't export anything the module doesn't own. I've only included this example to clarify what exports and require can do.

---

**Access an instance created in another module...** You can export the instance via the exports object as you would a constructor.

module.js...

```
function MySomething() {
    //...
}
exports.mySomething = new MySomething();
```

main.js...

```
var mySomething = require("./module").mySomething;
```

---

**Through an instance of an imported constructor, access an instance of a constructor that it has also imported...** You can expose it through the `this` scope in which case it will be accessible through the public members of the instance you create of the constructor you imported.

module.js...

```
var Something = require("./something").Something;
function MySomething() {
    this.something = new Something();
}
exports.MySomething = MySomething;
```

main.js...

```
var MySomething = require("./module").MySomething;
var mySomething = new MySomething();
mySomething.something;
```